# How to replace a token in the URL when calling HttpClient.get()

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

How to replace `${fooId}` token in the URL when calling `httpClient.get()` this way :

```
this.httpClient.get('http://my-server/foo/${fooId}');
```

Actually I'm using `this.httpClient.get('http://my-server/foo/${fooId}'.replace('${fooId}', fooId));` but I think it's not very clean

Comment: If the have the value You wanna replace with, why not simply set the value directly ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use backticks ``` `` ``` instead of simple quotes `'`

Comment: just as a note on this you can do the following:
`getRequest(fooId: number) {
   this.httpClient.get(\`http://my-server/foo/${fooId}\`);
}`

In this anything within `${}` will be TS/JS and not a string